# Web Scrapping en sitios con carga Dinamica JS

Tags: python, selenium, scraping, beautifulsoup, table

Estoy haciendo un trabajo de web scraping de la siguiente pagina: [Covid en chihuahua](https://saluddigital.ssch.gob.mx/covid/), lo que necesito hacer es generar un csv de la tabla que aparece en la pagina pero esta cargado con datos dinamicamente por lo cual estoy usando selenium. El problema es que aun asi no logro encontrar las tablas con el codigo el cual es el siguiente:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import time 
  
#url of the page we want to scrape 
url = "https://saluddigital.ssch.gob.mx/covid/"
  
# initiating the webdriver. Parameter includes the path of the webdriver. 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()  
driver.get(url)  
  
# this is just to ensure that the page is loaded 
html = driver.page_source 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(len(soup.find_all("table")))
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Cuando imprimo la tabla me sale 0 puesto que no la encuentra.

Comment: Hola Ulises! Tienes algunos errores en tú código, por favor corrigelos para poder se ayudado. En concreto estás usando un objeto `browser` que nunca ha sido definido, aunque supongo que en realidad será `driver`

Comment: Listo amigo, solo era cambiar eso.

Comment: Yo no reproduzco el problema